# Memory Leak when using memcpy in c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, operator-overloading, memcpy

Here is my pseudo code:

```
Class Product{
//code
};
Class ProductDiscount:public Product{
//code
};

Class Cart{

Product ** products;
int noElem;
};
```

And now what I had to do was to put all kind of products inside a Cart using
`cart += &product1;`(where product1 can be of type Product or ProductDiscount)

I did this by overloading += operator and here is the code:

```
void operator+=(Produs * prod){

    Produs ** copie = new Produs*[this->n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        memcpy(&copie[i], &produse[i], 4);



    this->n += 1;

    this->produse = new Produs*[this->n];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->n - 1; i++)
        memcpy(&produse[i], &copie[i], 4);


    memcpy(&produse[n - 1], &prod, sizeof(copie[0]));


}

void operator+=(ProdusDiscount * prod){

        Produs ** copie = new Produs*[this->n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            memcpy(&copie[i], &produse[i], 4);

        this->n += 1;

        this->produse = new Produs*[this->n];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->n - 1; i++)
            memcpy(&produse[i], &copie[i], 4);
        memcpy(&produse[n - 1], &prod, sizeof(copie[0]));

    }
```

Now, I want to know if there is another way of doing this. I also want to know if i'm generating a memory leak when I use memcpy and if so, how to avoid it.

Comment: The issue is not your use of `memcpy` but your failure to `delete[]` the things you `new[]`. There's no `delete[]` for `cpy`, and you overwrite `this->produse` without deleting the previous contents. I'm not sure why you even need `new` at all -- why are these things being dynamically allocated rather than using, for example, a `std::vector`?

Comment: Why are you using `memcpy` in C++ code?

Comment: I highly recommend removing the pointers and using `std::vector` to contain copies of objects.  You will avoid memory leak issues and other pointer related issues.

Comment: I've added `delete[] produse;` before `this->n +=1` and `delete[] copie;` at the end of the += operator overloading. It's okay now? I can't use `std::vector` because i'm restricted to do it in this way.

Comment: @EdHeal memcpy is perfectly legal C++.

Comment: FYI it is undefined behavior to use memcpy on a non trivially copyable object

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but you don't need `memcpy` anywhere in this code. Just assign the pointers. The compiler knows how to do that. So replace the first `memcpy` with `copie[i] = produse[i];` and so on.

Comment: @NathanOliver - but all the `memcpy`s here are copying pointer values. No undefined behavior, just lots of overhead and unneeded complexity.

Comment: @TonyJ there's a big difference between *legal* and *a good idea*.  The use of memcpy in this code is appalling

Comment: @M.M The questions was "Why are you using memcpy in C++ code?" Not "Why are you using memcpy in mordern C++ code?" Instead of asking the original question which is not constructive at all, an explaination for an alternative would be better, such as Thomas Matthews' comment.

Comment: @TonyJ the use of memcpy in this question has never been advisable in any iteration of C++.  There isn't enough info provided to post a definite answer but I'm guessing along the lines of Pete Becker's that an effect equivalent to simple assignment was intended.

Comment: @M.M At no point did I say memcpy is advisable. If you read my reply to you, you would see that "Why are  you using memcpy in C++ code?" does not actually help OP. Instead that, a constructive comment like Thomas Matthews is much better.